# UICollectionViewLayout that fills cells from the center to the sides, in one row

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

The `UICollectionView` that I want to make should have **only one row**, and it should fill like this:

```
1 element:         i  
2 elements:      i1 i2  
3 elements:    i3 i1 i2  
4 elements:   i3 i1 i2 i4
```

and so on.

I think I should subclass `UICollectionViewLayout` because `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` only fills in one direction.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes UICollectionViewLayout lays cells in grid manner.
If you like it to behave differently you certainly need custom layout.